# Stop touching___stop going around eveywhere

Tags: vocabulary

Looking for a right vocabulary. 
A kid is touching your leg, but his hand isn't just still, on the leg, but rather moving here and there busy. Do you have other words to describe this kind of touch?

Comment: Is it your own kid?

Comment: Please look up the definition of "vocabulary" in a dictionary.  [It does not mean what you think it means.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62835#62857)

Comment: Are you looking for a [word](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-request), or a [phrase](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-request)?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a colloquial way of telling your own child to desist:

> It annoys me when you keep touching my leg  over and over again like
>   that.

keep touching = persist in touching, to touch repeatedly

over and over again = repeatedly

like that = in that  manner, as you are doing

or you could  say

> What is this with all the touching? Stop doing it, okay?

or you could say

> Go away, kid. You're bothering me.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for:

> - [stroke](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stroke?s=t)
>
>   1. to pass the hand or an instrument over (something or somebody) lightly or with little pressure; rub gently, as in soothing or caressing.
> - [brush](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/brush?s=t)
>
>   11. to touch lightly in passing; pass lightly over:

So, it would be

> 1. Stop stroking my leg.
> 2. Stop brushing your hand on/against my leg.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the word Scrabble could be used here. It aptly fits the action mentioned here.
Could be said 
Stop scrabbling at my leg.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A dictionary reference might make it even more useful! If you haven't done so, please take a few minutes to review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. [From review](http://ell.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/46613)